# Why is this device power usage so much power and with such variation?

Tags: power, efficiency, power-consumption

I just got a wattage meter to try to get a sense of where my electricity usage is going. One of the surprises was my cheap drugstore humidifier, which seems to be drawing 640 watts. I have a huge basement dehumidifier that's only using 240 watts and substantial power tools that use even less.

The other strange thing is that the humidifier power usage jumps around dramatically. I made an animated gif of the usage, but it's too big to paste inline, so here's a link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/185m6o45ja6d6z7/humidifier-power.gif?raw=1

What it shows is the usage jumping constantly and widely, from 640W all the way down to 610W, just in a few seconds. It varies even more widely over longer observations.

So why is this little appliance using so much power and with such wild variation? Could it be defective, or even dangerous?

Comment: I can't be sure the meter is right, although it does seem to be measuring a 43W bulb at 43W. How do you calibrate these things?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank if DKNguyen is right, an incandescent light bulb, or an LED light bulb with good power factor correction is or looks like a resistive load, for which that  wattmeter works well. For all other loads: you can't calibrate it. It simply doesn't "see"  the phase of voltage vs current, so it has no info about what you need to measure.

Comment: However, a humidifier sounds mostly like a heater that evaporates water, maybe with a relatively small fan to blow things around. Is that diagnosis correct? If that's the case, the meter is probably right: Heating water takes a lot of power.

Comment: That's only a 5% variation... I wouldn't be too concerned about it. What's the power rating of the humidifier?

Comment: @MarcusMüller 640W is a lot of heat though. Six incandescent bulbs worth and I think that kind of heat would be pretty obvious from a humidifer. Also, I believe there are ultrasonic humidifiers that atomize the water rather than evaporate it.

Comment: Which wattmeter do you have? The *Kill A Watt* will measure Watts, VA, & Power Factor. Measure all 3 and post them if you can.

Comment: if the humidifier is the type that blows warm steam, then it is probably the type that passes current through the water to bring it to a boil, so there is no fixed heating element

Comment: @jsotola Wouldn't that electrolyze the water?

Comment: What type of humidifier is it? One that we bought just a couple of years ago was  container of water to which you added salt. The heating was caused by electrodes that were submerged in the salt solution. The current flow caused the water to boil and humidify the room. I was surprised that something so primitive could be sold these days. I didn't;t measure it but I would expect the bubbling around the electrodes would cause significant variation in the power consumption.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far. I need to do a little research into this device so I can provide the requested info.

Answer (score 0):

If your watt meter is crappy, it won't take into account power factor (but then I wouldn't really call it a wattmeter anymore since the whole point of a wattmeter is to see through the power factor). I kinda doubt your drugstore humidifer is drawing 640W.

You can't calibrate it. Voltage and current have to be in phase for real work to be done. When they are out of phase you get reactive power which is just real power moving back and forth not doing any work. To measure this it has to measure instantaneous voltage and current instant-to-instant. If your meter just measures voltage over time, and current over time, and then uses those two numbers to calculate power then it ignores the phase information.

It is like a warehouse that has imports and exports. If your imports and exports are staggered then your warehouse isn't ever really overfilled. But when not staggered you get a multiple consecutive import shipments accumulating in your warehouse before an export shipment can empty it out again. But you cannot see this effect if you just examined the average number of exports vs imports over a long period of time such as year or month. The phase information between imports and exports is not accounted.